# Operator << on template argument type member causes error only in clang

Tags: c++, templates, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

I have this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(const T &t) : m_t(t) {}
    void foo() {
        std::cout << m_t << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T m_t;
};

typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string> Type;
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Type &t) {
    os << std::get<0>(t) << " " << std::get<1>(t);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    A<Type> a(Type{"ala", " ma kota"});
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

which with clang++ (3.6) produces:

```
test_clang.cpp:10:19: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        std::cout << m_t << std::endl;
              ^
test_clang.cpp:26:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'A<std::tuple<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::foo' requested here
    a.foo();
      ^
test_clang.cpp:19:15: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Type &t) {
```

No errors occurred during g++-4.8 with C++11 and g++-5.2.1 with C++17 builds. clang++-3.6 needs `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Type &t)` to be defined *before* `A::foo<T>`.

From my perspective member `m_t` depends on template argument type and used `operator<<` for this type shouldn't be needed during template definition. Why clang has compilation error and g++ doesn't?

Comment: It seems 14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 7 (especially the last sentence) applies.

Comment: @DietmarKühl but there's no explicit specialization here, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string>
```

Let's look at the associated namespaces of this type. [basic.lookup.argdep]/(2.2):

> Its associated namespaces are the
>   innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes.

That would be namespace `std` or auxiliary ones, but certainly not the global namespace.

> Furthermore, if `T` is a class template specialization, its associated
>   namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes
>   associated with the types of the template arguments provided for
>   template type parameters (excluding template template parameters); [… inapplicable rules…]

Recursively applying the above to `std::string` gives namespace `std` (and, again, auxiliary ones) for the associated namespaces. Certainly not the global namespace. Clearly, the same argumentation can be repeated for `std::cout`, giving the same conclusion.

Thus **ADL won't look in the global namespace, which is precisely where your overload is declared in**.

Finally, as per [temp.dep.candidate]/1, name resolution is unsuccessful:

[image]

GCC behaves non-conforming here; see [**#51577**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577).

Comment: I know it's not in the scope of question itself - but, apart from moving definition of operator before definition of template, what would be the best solution to fix it?

Comment: @zoska Derive a global class from `std::tuple<std::string, std::string>`, inherit constructors and use it  more or less - as you would use a typedef?

Comment: that's what I thought (and tested, but seems I never know when I hit UB...). But I never feel comfortable when inheriting from stl containers, so I thought maybe there is a better solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait, why is this UB? That boxed paragraph applies only "if the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had **the lookup within the associated namespaces** considered all the function declarations with external linkage...". ADL will never find that `operator<<`. This looks like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577